# SwiftでNavigationControllerを使用した際にperformSegueWithIdentifierでエラー

Tags: ios, swift

Swift(iOS SDK8.4)で、NavigationControllerを使用して基点となるA画面からB画面に画面遷移を行うアプリケーションを構築しようとしていますが、
A画面で画面遷移をさせるボタンを押下した際に実行される performSegueWithIdentifier（） で、「has no segue with identifier 'next'」という内容で NSInvalidArgumentException が発生してしまい、行き詰まってしまっています。

NavigationControllerは以下のとおりAppDelegateに定義しています。

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var mainNavigationCtrl: UINavigationController?

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let first = FirstViewController()
    mainNavigationCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: first)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = mainNavigationCtrl
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
}
```

Storybord上にA画面とB画面をsegueで紐付けており、名前は'next'と定義しています。
A画面からB画面へは値を渡したいので、下記のとおりにコーディングしました。

```
class FirstViewController() {
  func onClick() {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
      if (segue.identifier == "next") {
          var view = segue.destinationViewController as! SecoundViewController
          view.lblName = self.Name.text!
      }
  }
}
```

AppDelegateのNavigationControllerをコメントアウトすると、performSegueWithIdentifierが正常に動作し、prepareForSegueへ処理が遷移してB画面へ値を渡した状態で遷移できました。

エラー解決方法や、そもそも実現方法に誤りがある等々、ご回答お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> エラー解決方法や、そもそも実現方法に誤りがある等々、ご回答お願いします。

はい、その「そもそも実現方法に誤りがある」です。
`AppDelegate`に記述したコードでは、`FirstViewController`のインスタンスを、Storyboardと結びつけていない状態で生成しています。Storyboardに結びついていないので、Storyboardを使った処理は、エラーになります。
Storyboardと結びついた`UIViewController`を生成するには、`UIStoryboard`クラスの`instantiateInitialViewController()`か`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()`メソッドを使います。前者を使うと、

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // Storyboardの名称は、任意。
    mainNavigationCtrl = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = mainNavigationCtrl
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

ただし、これはアプリの設定で指定したStoryboard以外のStoryboardを使用する場合の処理です。`AppDelegate`になにも記述しなければ、デフォルトのStoryboardから起動します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、Storyboardとの紐付けができていなかったのですね...。  
NavigationControllerを使用したいので、ご指摘いただいたとおりStorybordと結びつけたところFirstViewControllerのperformSegueWithIdentifierも正常に通過し、次画面へ値渡しをすることができました。  
  
しかし、次は遷移先のB画面でNavigationControllerが非表示になってしまいました。  
ひとまず、当質問としては解決していますので、解決済みにさせていただきますが、もし事象に心当たりがあればご回答お願いします。